# Can't use assertViewHas method in my test

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.5, mockery

I'm learning Laravel testing and I wish to use [Laravel Framework Assertions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/testing#framework-assertions).

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->mock = Mockery::mock("Eloquent", "Post");
}

public function testIndex()
{
    $this->mock
       ->shouldReceive('all')
       ->once()
       ->andReturn('foo');

    $this->app->instance('Post', $this->mock);
    $this->call('GET', 'posts');
    $this->assertViewHas('posts'); // This method seem can't be find 
}
```

It seems that `assertViewHas` method does not exists because my IDE can't autocomplete that method It can't find it, but when I search in the Laravel 5.5 API I find that method in the [assertViewHas](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.html#method_assertViewHas) method in the `TestResponse` class in  `Illuminate/Foundation/Testing` namespace.
How can I solve this problem.

Another problem is that in this test I'm using mockery to mock my `Post` model, but a get some error when I run `vendor\bin\phpunit`in my terminal.

[image: PHP unit Error]

I don't find where the `array_merge()` is used in my test

Comment: Is your test class extending Laravel's `TestCase` class?

Comment: Show your code where you call `array_merge`, though it should really be a separate question.

Comment: Yes! my class extends `Tests\TestCase` of laravel

Comment: @Jeffwa I don't use array_merge nowhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$this->call('GET', 'posts');
$this->assertViewHas('posts'); // This method seem can't be find
```

you should use

```
$response = $this->call('GET', 'posts');
$response->assertViewHas('posts');
```

Default way of running tests was changed in Laravel 5.4 See [Upgrade guide - Testing section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade) for details.